# How to operate over pandas dataframe columns where the column name is a datetime string with a suffix?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, generator

Ultimately, I am trying to calculate and then graph the price elasticity of demand for housing from 2010 to 2016 across 290 U.S. Counties.

Elasticity of demand is equal to the % change in quantity divided by the % change in price.

The data I have is from Zillow: 'InventoryMeasure_County_Public.csv' and 'City_Zhvi_AllHomes.csv'.

The data are in a multi-indexed pandas DataFrame containing time series data. It looks like this, although with 55 columns and 290 rows:

```
PQ = pd.DataFrame({ "2010q1_x":[0.1, 0.2, 0.3],
                           "2010q2_x":[0.2, 0.2, 0.2],
                                                    # ... goes to 2016q4_x
                           "2010q1_y":[2.1, 2.2, 2.3],
                           "2010q2_y":[1.2, 1.2, 1.3],
                                                    # ... goes to 2016q4_y           
              } index = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(
              [('Alabama', 'Huntsville'), ('Alabama','Rainbow City') 
                                                    # ... for all 50 States
               ('Wyoming', 'Burton County'), ('Wyoming', 'Joe Falls')],
                names=['State','County'])))
```

I seem to only be able to perform one operation at a time. For example:

```
PQ['2010q1_x'].div(PQ['2010q1_y'])
```

yields:

```
State       County         

Alabama     Madison             -0.017560

            Mobile              -0.112925

            Shelby              -0.100689

            Tuscaloosa           0.319638

Alaska      Anchorage            0.261926

            Juneau               0.099720

Arizona     Maricopa            -0.003240

            Pima                 0.098894

            Yuma                -1.982047
                                          # ... and so on.
```

Which is perfect, it's exactly what I need. I just need to do the operation over each of the 55 columns without having to write 55 expressions. 
I would like to write something like this:

```
(PQ['20{}q{}_x'.format([x for x in range(10,17)],[x for x in range(1,5)])])
               .div(PQ['20{}q{}_y'.format([x for x in range(10,17)],[x for x in range(1,5)])])
```

However, when I run the above code, there is a key error:

```
KeyError: '20[10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16]q[1, 2, 3, 4]_x'
```

I found these, however, they didn't give me anything conclusive.

[Python documentation for operators](https://docs.python.org/2/library/operator.html)

[Can generators be used with .format?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18472436/can-generators-be-used-with-string-format-in-python)

[Adding Dataframes with same column names](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36245392/how-to-add-dataframes-where-the-column-names-are-same)

I also tried converting the columns in the DataFrame to np.arrays, where I was able to successfully operate across both data, however, when I attempted to add the results to the multi-indexed DataFrame, the results were all NaN.

I also tried 'de-multi-indexing': I changed the index to the tuples of the State, County pairs to see if the problem was with the multi-index.

Hopefully I have been relatively clear in explaining this - my end goal is really very simple, and I am sure I'm just over-thinking this.

Thank you in advance for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let use .str.extract to group columns then divide.

Input:

```
print(PQ)

                       2010q1_x  2010q1_y  2010q2_x  2010q2_y
State   County                                               
Alabama Huntsville          0.1       2.1       0.2       1.2
        Rainbow City        0.2       2.2       0.2       1.2
Wyoming Burton County       0.3       2.3       0.2       1.3

df_out = PQ.groupby(by=PQ.columns.str.extract('(\d{4}q\d)',expand=False),axis=1).apply(lambda x: x.iloc[:,0].div(x.iloc[:,1]))

print(df_out)
```

Output:

```
                         2010q1    2010q2
State   County                           
Alabama Huntsville     0.047619  0.166667
        Rainbow City   0.090909  0.166667
Wyoming Burton County  0.130435  0.153846
```

Comment: This works perfectly! It didn't even occur to me to use groupby.

Answer (score 1):

I like the groupby() approach by @Scott Boston, but here's another way

```
import pandas as pd

PQ = pd.DataFrame({ "2010q1_x":[0.1, 0.2, 0.3],
                   "2010q2_x":[0.2, 0.2, 0.2],
                           "2010q1_y":[2.1, 2.2, 2.3],
                           "2010q2_y":[1.2, 1.2, 1.3]}, index = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(
              [('Alabama', 'Huntsville'), ('Alabama','Rainbow City'),
               ('Wyoming', 'Burton County')],
                names=['State','County']))
print (PQ)
                       2010q1_x  2010q1_y  2010q2_x  2010q2_y
State   County                                               
Alabama Huntsville          0.1       2.1       0.2       1.2
        Rainbow City        0.2       2.2       0.2       1.2
Wyoming Burton County       0.3       2.3       0.2       1.3
```

using pandas `filter` we can divide the "_x" columns by values in the "_y" columns

```
eods = PQ.filter(like='_x') / PQ.filter(like='_y').values
```

after some column name cleanup it yields

```
eods.columns = eods.columns.str.replace('_x','_eod')
print (eods)
                       2010q1_eod  2010q2_eod
State   County                               
Alabama Huntsville       0.047619    0.166667
        Rainbow City     0.090909    0.166667
Wyoming Burton County    0.130435    0.153846
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if there is more skill way to do this, but this method can success.

```
# create an empty DataFrame to store result
result = pd.DataFrame(None, 
                 columns=pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(list(zip(['20{}q{}_x'.format(x, y) for x in range(10,17) for y in range(1,5)], 
                                               ['20{}q{}_x'.format(x, y) for x in range(10,17) for y in range(1,5)])),
                                                  names=['numerator', 'denominator']),
                index=PQ.index
                )

# fill the result
result = result.apply(lambda s: PQ[s.name[0]].div(PQ[s.name[1]]))
```